# coinbase Pro python login error

Tags: python, coinbase-api

I am using this simple code to login to CoinBase Pro account.

```
 secretKey = "xx"
 key = "yy"

from coinbase.wallet.client import Client
client = Client(key,secretKey)

user = client.get_current_user()
```

It is giving me the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<input>", line 9, in <module>
File "/Users/rishibhatt/venv/CoinBase/lib/python3.6/site-    packages/coinbase/wallet/client.py", line 220, in get_current_user
 response = self._get('v2', 'user', params=params)
File "/Users/rishibhatt/venv/CoinBase/lib/python3.6/site-   packages/coinbase/wallet/client.py", line 129, in _get
 return self._request('get', *args, **kwargs)
File "/Users/rishibhatt/venv/CoinBase/lib/python3.6/site-   packages/coinbase/wallet/client.py", line 116, in _request
  return self._handle_response(response)
File "/Users/rishibhatt/venv/CoinBase/lib/python3.6/site-packages/coinbase/wallet/client.py", line 125, in _handle_response
 raise build_api_error(response)
coinbase.wallet.error.AuthenticationError:    APIError(id=authentication_error): invalid api key
```

I can't find any post related to this error. Can someone please explain the error or direct me to the correct post?

PS: I generated the API keys just today.

Comment: Coinbase Pro API (formerly GDax API) is not the same as the Coinbase API. Are you sure the module you have installed is for Coinbase Pro API and just Coinbase API - I'm suspecting the latter because Coinbase Pro also requires a `passphrase` as part of its authentication procedure?

Comment: Its Coinbase. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, Coinbase Pro API is different from Coinbase API and you must change the package you are importing.

Answer (score 0):

The repository you are after is linked following:

https://github.com/danpaquin/coinbasepro-python

Feel free to post additional issues in the repository for community feedback.